# Objective C: No @interface declares the selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class called TAPJSONPoster. It's .h is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TAPJsonPoster : NSObject
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url WithJson:(NSData*)jsondata;
-(NSData*)getResponse;

@end
```

It's .m is:

```
#import "TAPJsonPoster.h"
@interface TAPJsonPoster()
@property NSURL *url;
@property NSData *jsondata;

@end

@implementation TAPJsonPoster
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)url WithJson:(NSData*)jsondata
{
    self=[super init];
    self.url=url;
    self.jsondata=jsondata;

    return self;

}

-(NSData*)getResponse
{
    return self.jsondata;


}
@end
```

I still have tto fill in getResponse, but the init itself is not working. In my ViewController I have

```
#import "TAPJSONPostConnector.h"
```

and a method to login:

```
- (IBAction)loginValidate:(id)sender {
    NSString *username=self.unTextField.text;
    NSString *password=self.pwdTextField.text;
    NSArray *params=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userId",@"password", nil];
    NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"_requestName", @"login",
                       @"_ParamNames", params,
                       @"userId", username,
                       @"password", password,
                       nil];
    NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"loginURL"];
    TAPJSONPostConnector *connector=[[TAPJSONPostConnector alloc] initWithURL:url WithJson:data];



}
```

The last line where I am making the PostConnector is giving me an error saying that

> No @interface in TAPJSONPostConnector declares the selector initWithURL:WithJson

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** 
I put in [connector getResponse] below the connector initialization and I get the same error for this method also, am I doin something wrong in importing?

Comment: try `initWithURL:url withJson:data` ... it is case sensitive

Comment: Unless `TAPJSONPostConnector` is a subclass of `TAPJsonPoster` you're just talking to the wrong class here.

Comment: It's TAPJsonPoster, but not TAPJSONPostConnector that has that function.

Comment: @Alladinian Thanks, such an embarrassing mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're calling the `initWithURL:withJson:` initializer on TAPJSONPostConnector

```
TAPJSONPostConnector *connector=[[TAPJSONPostConnector alloc] initWithURL:url WithJson:data];
```

But it looks like this is declared on the `TAPJsonPoster` class. Perhaps this is what you meant.

```
TAPJsonPoster *connector=[[TAPJsonPoster alloc] initWithURL:url WithJson:data];
```

Comment: Ok I'm so embarrassed, I don't know what I was thinking to make such a mistake. I actually broke my head for an hour over such a silly thing, lack of sleep. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Either you're allocating a wrong object `TAPJSONPostConnector` instead of `TAPJsonPoster`

```
TAPJsonPoster *connector=[[TAPJsonPoster alloc] initWithURL:url WithJson:data];
```

Or you forgot to change the super class for `TAPJSONPostConnector` as `TAPJsonPoster`

```
@interface TAPJSONPostConnector : TAPJsonPoster
```

Change whatever fits your needs

One tip if you can change the name of method `initWithURL: withJson:` that will be according to the naming convetion